# How do I make a loop that checks for new IBAction input on every iteration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, uiviewcontroller

I want to make a loop that plays a sound file (a very brief beep) and waits time equal to delay then repeats, this loop runs until I hit the pause button and the wait time delay can be changed via a slider button while the loop is running.

```
- (void)playSound 
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Metronome-Sound.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audioPlayer play];
}

- (IBAction)playSelected:(UIButton *)sender
{
if (stateOfMetronome == 0){
    stateOfMetronome = 1;
    while (stateOfMetronome == 1){   
        [self playSound];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:delay];
    }
} 
}


- (IBAction)pauseSeleted:(UIButton *)sender
{
if (stateOfMetronome == 1){
    stateOfMetronome = 0;
    [audioPlayer pause];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most painless way to achieve this I think is to use a [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) set to repeat.  When you need to stop/pause it, just invalidate the timer.  When you want to start it, simply reinitialize it.  Using this method, you can painlessly control when to fire with a delay as well as easily customize the interval.

Also, keep in mind, that you could potentially block all UI interaction when sleeping your thread.  This may mean that you are unable to play/pause while the thread is asleep as there is no runloop processing while asleep.  See details on [NSThread](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yes, PLEASE use NSTimer. Polling loops are evil.

Comment: I just started developing for the iPhone so it looks like I've got some learning to do. Thank you.